# Create dymanic textboxes in button onclick & save data to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to create dynamic textboxes using php & jquery. I want to submit a paper for presentation, each presentation have more than one authors and each author have more than one affiliations. I tried to create dynamic text boxes for authors and their affiliations. I can create authors dynamically up to 10 but affiliations for only 1st author. Anybody please help me to correct this code. Thanks

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>author</title>
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<style type="text/css">
 div{
  padding:8px;
 }
</style>
 
</head>
 
<body>
 
<h1>Author</h1>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
 
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    var counter = 2;
 
    $("#addAuthor").click(function () {
 
 if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 authores allow");
            return false;
 }   //addAffiliation
 
 var newauthorDiv = $(document.createElement('div')) 
      .attr("id", 'authorDiv' + counter);
 
 newauthorDiv.after().html('<label> <b> Author '+ counter + ' </b> </label>' +
  '<br><label>Name : </label>' +
       '<input type="text" name="author1_name' + counter + '" id="author1_name' + counter + '" value="" >'+
    '<div id="AffiliationGroup"><label>Affiliation 1 : </label>' +
       '<input type="text" name="author' + counter + 'affiliation' +  counter +
       '" id="author' + counter + 'affiliation' +  counter +'" value="" >' + 
    '<input type="button" id="addAffiliation" value="+" >' +
    '<input type="button" id="removeAffiliation" value="-" >' + '</div>');
 
 newauthorDiv.appendTo("#AuthorGroup");
 
 
 counter++;
     });
 
     $("#removeAuthor").click(function () {
 if(counter==1){
          alert("No more author to remove");
          return false;
       }   
 
 counter--;
 
        $("#authorDiv" + counter).remove();
 
     });
 
     $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {
 
 var msg = '';
 for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
      msg += "\n Author " + i + " : " + $('#author' + i).val();
 }
       alert(msg);
     });
  });
  
  
  // Affiliation 
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
 
    var counter = 2;
 
    $("#addAffiliation").click(function () {
 
 if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 Affiliations allow");
            return false;
 }   
 
 var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
      .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
 
 newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label> Affiliation '+ counter + ' : </label>' +
       '<input type="text" name="author1_affiliation' + counter + 
       '" id="author1_affiliation' + counter + '" value="" >');
 
 newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#AffiliationGroup");
 
 
 counter++;
     });
 
     $("#removeAffiliation").click(function () {
 if(counter==1){
          alert("No more Affiliations to remove");
          return false;
       }   
 
 counter--;
 
        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
 
     });
 
     $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {
 
 var msg = '';
 for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
      msg += "\n Affiliation " + i + " : " + $('#author1_affiliation' + i).val();
 }
       alert(msg);
     });
  });
  
</script>
</head><body>
 
<div id='AuthorGroup'>

  <label><b>Author 1 </b></label> <br>
        <label>Name : </label><input type='author' id='author1_name1' >
       
        <div id='AffiliationGroup'>
   <label>Affiliation 1 : </label><input type='textbox' id='author1_affiliation1' > 
        <input type='button' value='+' id='addAffiliation'>
        <input type='button' value='-' id='removeAffiliation'>
        <!--<input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'>-->
  </div>    
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add Author' id='addAuthor'>
<input type='button' value='Remove Author' id='removeAuthor'>
<!--<input type='button' value='Get author Value' id='getButtonValue'>-->
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you saying that there should not be any Affiliation  box from the second author??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/9y3n33jx/

I haven't completed the whole thing but it should give you an idea.

You need to put your original author inside a `div.authorDiv`. Use class names instead of id for your + - buttons.

```
    <input type='button' value='+' class='addAffiliation'>
    <input type='button' value='-' class='removeAffiliation'>
```

Because those buttons will be dynamically added you need to bind to click event on `body` for the button class:

```
$('body').on("click", ".addAffiliation", function () {
```

(When the button is clicked you need to figure out the number of affiliates inside div by class, i.e. $(this).parent().(".affiliateClass").length)

When the add button is clicked, you need to add the new div to the parent of the clicked button:

```
newTextBoxDiv.appendTo($(this).closest(".authorDiv"));
```

You'll have to do the same for the - button. This should get you going in the right ddirection.